# Reference request for improper integrals.

Tags: analysis, reference-request, improper-integrals

I am an undergrad student.We have a course on improper integrals of first and second kind along with beta and gamma function.I am looking for a suitable text that describes the problems and theory in detail.I have referred to S K Mapa,Real analysis but the book is not suitable for me.Can someone suggest any analysis text for improper integrals.

I am looking for the following subtopics:

$1.$ Improper integrals $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ with infinite discontinuity at $a$ and $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ in which range of integration is unbounded.

$2.$ Tests for improper integrals such as Comparison test,$\mu$-test etc.

$3.$ Beta gamma function and properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emanuel Fischer, *Intermediate Real Analysis*, Chapter XV, page 710. The matter about Gamma and Beta functions is discussed in page 726 - 735.

Comment: the pdf is not available.

Comment: Hey, of course you don't expect that. But I believe that university library will have that, as I have stayed in three universities, there is the book.